# Lookup, group and calculate in mongoose based on two different collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am having a hard time understanding aggregation. What I am trying to do is to find all records from one collection and then lookup another collection and do some calculation on it, then return response with everything consolidated.

**Exam Schema**

```
const examSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    examName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, "Exam name is missing"],
        maxlength: [60, "Max exam name length is 60 characters"],
    },
    duration: {
        type: Number,
        trim: true,
        default: 0,
        min: [0, "Minimum exam duration is zero minutes"],
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Exam", examSchema);
```

**Question Schema**

```
const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _refExamId: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Exam",
    }],
    title: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, "Question is missing"],
    },
    positiveMarks: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "Marks for the question is missing"],
        default: 0,
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Question", questionSchema);
```

***_refExamId*** here is an array as there are chances that a single question might be used in multiple exams.

So, what I would like is to query the **exams** collection and get all the exams and its related questions and the total marks count of each exam.

**Desired Output**

```
{
    exam_name: "Demo exam 1",
    total_time: 30,
    total_marks: 50,
    questions: [{ title: "Question 1" }, { title: "Question 2" }]
},
{
    exam_name: "Demo exam 2",
    total_time: 0,
    total_marks: 0,
    questions: []
}
.
.
.
```

**What I have done**

```
const exams = await examModel.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "questions",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "_refExamId",
            as: "questions"
        },
    }
]);

console.log(exams);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good, you're working towards the right path.

The following pipeline would give you the desired output.

```js
const result = await Exam.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'questions',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: '_refExamId',
      as: 'questions'
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      exam_name: '$examName',
      total_time: '$duration',
      total_marks: {
        $reduce: {
          input: '$questions',
          initialValue: 0,
          in: { $add: ['$$value', '$$this.positiveMarks'] }
        }
      },
      questions: {
        $map: {
          input: '$questions',
          as: 'question',
          in: { title: '$$question.title' }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Here's a full reproduction script using Node.js, MongoDB, and mongoose:

#### 65198206.js

```js
'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;


run().catch(console.error);

async function run () {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  });

  await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();


  const examSchema = new Schema({
    examName: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, 'Exam name is missing'],
      maxlength: [60, 'Max exam name length is 60 characters']
    },
    duration: {
      type: Number,
      trim: true,
      default: 0,
      min: [0, 'Minimum exam duration is zero minutes']
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });

  const Exam = mongoose.model('Exam', examSchema);


  const questionSchema = new Schema({
    _refExamId: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Exam'
    }],
    title: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, 'Question is missing']
    },
    positiveMarks: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'Marks for the question is missing'],
      default: 0
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });


  const Question = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);



  const exams = await Exam.create([
    { examName: 'A', duration: 70 },
    { examName: 'B', duration: 90 }
  ]);
  await Question.create([
    {
      _refExamId: [
        exams[0]._id, exams[1]._id
      ],
      title: 'Question a',
      positiveMarks: 10
    },
    {
      _refExamId: [
        exams[0]._id, exams[1]._id
      ],
      title: 'Question b',
      positiveMarks: 20
    },
    {
      _refExamId: [
        exams[0]._id, exams[1]._id
      ],
      title: 'Question c',
      positiveMarks: 30
    }
  ]);

  const result = await Exam.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'questions',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: '_refExamId',
        as: 'questions'
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        exam_name: '$examName',
        total_time: '$duration',
        total_marks: {
          $reduce: {
            input: '$questions',
            initialValue: 0,
            in: { $add: ['$$value', '$$this.positiveMarks'] }
          }
        },
        questions: {
          $map: {
            input: '$questions',
            as: 'question',
            in: { title: '$$question.title' }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
}
```

#### Output

```
$ node 65198206.js
[
  {
    "_id": "5fcf6ea22bd478354c14ad42",
    "exam_name": "A",
    "total_time": 70,
    "total_marks": 60,
    "questions": [
      {
        "title": "Question a"
      },
      {
        "title": "Question b"
      },
      {
        "title": "Question c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5fcf6ea22bd478354c14ad43",
    "exam_name": "B",
    "total_time": 90,
    "total_marks": 60,
    "questions": [
      {
        "title": "Question a"
      },
      {
        "title": "Question b"
      },
      {
        "title": "Question c"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Just curious why cant we use `$group` instead of `$project`?

Comment: Because you don't need to group any documents of the current stage, you have all the data needed for your desired output, you just need to reformat it and do some calculations. A second `$group` stage is likely slower.

Comment: one more question, how do we get the count of matched `$questions`?

Comment: You can use `$size` operator. Add the following property inside the `$project` stage. `questionsCount: { $size: '$questions' }`

Comment: I was trying out with count after adding another lookup stage and it seemed so complicated.